# stsadm -migrateuser -oldlogin ABC\52339 -newlogin DEF\52339 ... Access Denied

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, stsadm, migrate

in SharePoint 2007 command prompt at this location:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN\

I type this command to migrate user from one domain to another like:

stsadm -migrateuser -oldlogin ABC\52339 -newlogin DEF\52339

I got "Access denied" message. Why is that?

Comment: which account you are using to run stsadm? you  should use administrator account

Comment: Also make sure to run the command prompt with 'run as administrator' if UAC is enabled

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN\stsadm.exe" -o migrateuser -oldlogin "i:0#.w|domainname\personName " -newlogin "i:0#.w domainname\personName" –ignoresidhistory
```